# Constants of structure of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

> By definition, a basis of an $A$-algebra is a basis of $E$ for its
> $A$-module structure. Let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $E;$ there
> exists a unique family $(\gamma_{ij}^k)_{(i,j,k)\in I\times I\times
>  I}$ of elements on the ring $A$ such that for every ordered pair
> $(i,j)\in I\times I$, the set of $k\in I$ such that
> $\gamma_{i,j}^k\ne0$ is finite and  $$a_ia_j=\sum_{k\in
>  I}\gamma_{ij}^ka_k,$$

Does the "$k$" in the expression $\gamma_{ij}^k$ stand for a power or an index? It seems to me, the latter. Let $i,j\in I$. Then $a_ia_j\in E$; there exists a unique $\lambda_{ij}\in A^{(I)}$ such that
$$a_ia_j=\sum_{k\in I}\lambda_{ij}(k)a_k.$$
Then my $\lambda_{ij}(k)$ would be written as $\lambda_{ij}^k$ in the author's notation, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it stands for an index. The product $a_ia_j$ has a linear representation in terms of the basis $\{a_i\mid i\in I\}$.
A better notation would be $\gamma_{ij}^{(k)}$ or $\gamma_{ijk}$.